# Modal doesnt close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, modal-dialog

I have a self calling form in PHP. The idea is that when a non registered user (Joomla) clicks on a button in the form, upon POST a modal should show up and say that "you are not logged in". Now when I do the following, the Modal opens up but it doesn't close.

```
if(JFactory::getUser()->guest) {
    echo '  
    <div id="ModalStart" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>You are not logged in </h4><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    }
```

Comment: Any JS Errors showing in chrome dev tools?

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. - I see this while doing the page inspect

Comment: What JS file is this in? Bootstrap? presumably this is the case in all browsers btw?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to use twitter bootstrap. Yes the behavior is the same in all browsers.